# encapsulate fields without lambda expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I started using visual studio 2019 and when encapsulating it uses lamda expressions and I want it to generate the properties as it was traditionally ..

```
public decimal DecimalValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _decimalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _decimalValue = value;
        }
    }
```

try to edit the code editor text editor edit options, but changing and accepting does not save the changes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDvuJ.jpg)

Comment: I am 90% sure those are *not* lambda expression. They are the proper way to do Properties. Always were.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, those are expression body syntax. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

Answer (score 0):

Properties are just syntax sugar for a `getValue()` and a `setValue()` function.

What you wrote there is not a lambda. The lack of the Lambda operator (`=>`) is sure sign. It is really just a function signature, minus the argument and return type - as those are infered from/decided by the property.

That is and has always been [how Properties are defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in C#. So no idea wich "original" way of writing them you are talking about.

Since your code is rather simple, maybe what you want is the auto-implement properties? Where the compiler takes care of the backing field for you, so you can not accidentally access it?

```
public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
```

But chronologically those [actually came later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

Comment: what i am trying to do is when i type a field for example private int myVar;
and I right click on quick actions, then encapsulate field and keep using it that the result is
private int myVar;
         public int MyProperty
         {
             get {return myVar; }
             set {myVar = value; }
         }
but it generates the following
private int myVar;
public int MyVar {get => myVar; set => myVar = value; }

Comment: @FabianWesling It would be ideal if you inserted that code into your original post. But at the very least, add t he Syntax Highlighting for comments. So my first comment is about fixing that: `private int myVar; public int MyProperty { get {return myVar; } set {myVar = value; } }` and `private int myVar; public int MyVar {get => myVar; set => myVar = value; }`

Comment: @FabianWesling The core job of a property is that you do not accidentally access the backing field **especially** in class code. Accidental writing of the backing field is the worst case for properties The pattern calls for appending a underscore prefix to the backing field `_DecimalValue`, so you can not possibly access it by accident when you wanted `DecimalValue`. | Autoimplement properties as I wrote them have a backing field. It just has no name, so there is no way for you to access it with code. Ever.

Comment: @FabianWesling So: Do you *want* a code accessible backing field? Or do you *need* a coded out get/set? If the answer is no to both: Autoimplement properties. | If the answer to any one of them is yes: What you wrote is what you get. Lambdas may make the written code a bit shorter, but do not really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use propfull code snippet.
Type ***propfull*** and hit tab button twice.
It will not refactor existing field, but it will add a new private field exposed through a property